# Using a condition to check if a field is null before populating with next value in sequence

Tags: sql, db2

This is currently working as expected except i want it to not populate an acctnum with the next value in the sequence if it is null.  My problem is when trying to next an if statement inside my FROM FINAL TABLE.  It doesnt like it at all. This is a syntax problem and i have googled this to no avail.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE acct_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MAXVALUE
NO CYCLE
CACHE 24
;

SELECT accntnum  AS new_acct, old_acct
FROM FINAL TABLE (
UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)
SET accntnum = NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq, old_acct = accntnum
)
ORDER BY old_acct;
```

The reason im doing this is so i can return both the new and old account number. i Still want to return the new and old accnt number even if they are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface that could have been accomplished by using a `CASE` expression in the `UPDATE` statement, like

```
...
UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)
SET 
  accntnum = CASE WHEN accntnum IS NOT NULL THEN NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq END, 
...
```

However, DB2 does not allows the use of `NEXT VALUE` in a CASE expression. Since you are only updating non-NULL values in `accntnum`, you can explicitly specify so in the `UPDATE` statement and return NULLs for the unmodified rows if you need to.

```
SELECT accntnum  AS new_acct, old_acct
FROM FINAL TABLE (
  UPDATE accounts INCLUDE(old_acct INT)
  SET accntnum = NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq, old_acct = accntnum
  WHERE accntnum IS NOT NULL
)
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as new_acct, NULL as old_acct
FROM accounts 
WHERE accntnum IS NULL
ORDER BY old_acct;
```

Comment: I believe thats what i want but i am getting an error. the line im trying to use is `accntnum = CASE WHEN accntnum IS NOT NULL THEN cast(cast(NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq as CHAR(17)) as VARCHAR(17)) END`  But im getting an error.  it was working before i added the case.

Comment: Should we all start guessing what error you get, or may be you choose to tell us?

Comment: sorry.  `SQL0348N  "NEXTVAL" cannot be specified in this context.  SQLSTATE=428F9`

Comment: Limiting the update to rows where accntnum is not null might work, but i still want to return an old_acct and new_acct as being null

Comment: I did this
`SET accntnum = cast(cast(NEXT VALUE FOR acct_seq as CHAR(17)) as VARCHAR(17)), old_accntnum  = accntnum WHERE accntnum IS NOT NULL`  

which is running almost as i want it to.  I still want to return the  records with null values as a new/old like i am for the rest of them.

Comment: Well, since you are not updating what's NULL, a `UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE accntnum IS NULL` should do the trick, no?

Comment: could you edit your original response to show the correct syntax of this in respect to the rest of the query?

Comment: getting `SQL0348N  "NEXTVAL FOR E3                                                        " cannot be specified in this context.`